General solution of an ODE
I have the following ODE
$$xy''+(2s+1-2x)y'+(\beta-2s-1)y=0$$
The funny constants are there because it arises from a physics problem. However, I'm trying to solve it by expansion into power series because I'm not that well vesed into hypegeometric functions and Laguerre polynomials:
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
And what I get as the recursion formula for the coefficients is:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{2n-\beta+2s+1}{(n+1)(n+2s+1)}a_n$$
But this means that I get one basis vector in the two-dimensional space of solutions of the linear ODE, so no general solution there. Can you explain why is that the case? And if you know why doesn't the other linearly independent solution matter (the context is colving the Morse potential)

There is avery strong relation between Tricomi's hypergeometric function and Laguerre polynomials. This explains that.

Take a look at Frobenius method.
